# Index for OR operator: a=x or b=x

Tags: postgresql, index, performance, postgresql-performance

I have table with three integer columns `id`, `a` and `b`.
I want to get all records where `a` or `b` match specified parameter ordered by `id`:

```
select id, a, b from t where a=x or b=x order by id
```

Note that `x` value is same for `a` and `b`.

What it the most suitable index here?

Upd: Is there any use of the fact that we always look for *same* value in columns `a` and `b`? Can we create an expression index for that?

Comment: See if [this discussion](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/110636/postgres-poor-performance-on-order-by-id-desc-limit-1) is useful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simple and fast solution are two indexes on `(a, id)` and `(b, id)`. Be sure to have `a` respectively `b` as *leading* column:

- [Working of indexes in PostgreSQL](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/6115/working-of-indexes-in-postgresql/7484#7484)

The added `id` is not going to help for your particular query, you could as well just create them on `(a)` and `(b)` to get the bitmap index scans that [@shx explained](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/132931/3684). But the index for two integer is exactly as big as for one column. There may be other use cases that actually benefit from the added `id`.

- [Is a composite index also good for queries on the first field?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/27481/is-a-composite-index-also-good-for-queries-on-the-first-field?lq=1)

If your actual `SELECT` list is narrow like in your example and *some preconditions are met*, I would go for [**index-only scans**](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Index-only_scans).
Create indexes on `(a, b, id)` and `(b, a, id)`.

This equivalent query (given that `id` or at least `(id,a,b)` is unique) helps Postgres choose the query plan with index-only scans:

```
EXPLAIN
SELECT id,a,b FROM t WHERE a = 10
UNION
SELECT id,a,b FROM t WHERE b = 10
ORDER  BY id;
```

```
Sort  (cost=110.45..112.92 rows=988 width=12)
  Sort Key: t.id
  ->  HashAggregate  (cost=51.42..61.31 rows=988 width=12)
        Group Key: t.id, t.a, t.b
        ->  Append  (cost=0.42..44.02 rows=988 width=12)
              ->  Index Only Scan using t_ab_id_idx on t  (cost=0.42..17.07 rows=494 width=12)
                    Index Cond: (a = 10)
              ->  Index Only Scan using t_ba_id_idx on t t_1  (cost=0.42..17.07 rows=494 width=12)
                    Index Cond: (b = 10)
```

Performance depends on data distribution, write patterns and value frequencies, among other things. In my tests on pg 9.5 I see similar performance to the solution in @shx's answer - as long as we select *whole rows* (i.e. heap tuples are not much bigger than index tuples).

Typically, there are additional columns in the underlying table - which would not impair performance of this query at all, while the alternative loses ground since it has to read more pages for wider rows in the underlying table.

### Answer to added question

> Is there any use of the fact that we always look for same value in columns a and b? Can we create an expression index for that?

I can't think of a way to capitalize on that for the table as is. An index entry can only reference a *single* table row. Theoretically, a GIN index on `(ARRAY[a,b])` *might work*, but I could not get useful results with it (nor did I expect to).

You would need *two* rows per row in the base table (except where `a = b`) to enable a single pass on a b-tree index for the job. Actually possible with the help of a [**`MATERIALIZED VIEW`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-creatematerializedview.html). The added overhead and maintenance cost only seems reasonable if you have *much* more read than write activity and you need to optimize performance for your given query. You need to understand MVs and know when to refresh.

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW mv_t AS
SELECT a AS x, id, a, b FROM t
UNION  -- eliminate dupes
SELECT b AS x, id, a, b FROM t
ORDER  BY x, id;
```

`x` is the unified search key. Rows in the base table are listed once for every distinct value in `[a, b]`. This query returns the same result as your original, but faster:

```
SELECT id,a,b FROM mv_t WHERE x = 10 ORDER BY id;
```

The query can benefit from a *single* pass on a *single* index now. Plus, rows in the MV are sorted physically like they are returned, which helps the approach with a simple index:

```
CREATE INDEX mv_t_x_idx ON mv_t (x); -- simple
```

```
Sort  (cost=88.01..90.48 rows=990 width=12)
  Sort Key: id
  ->  Index Scan using mv_t_x_idx on mv_t  (cost=0.42..38.75 rows=990 width=12)
        Index Cond: (x = 10)
```

Also ideal for a BRIN index (Postgres 9.5+) for huge tables:

- [Speed up creation of Postgres partial index](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/102509/speed-up-creation-of-postgres-partial-index/102513#102513)

You can go for index-only scans again:

```
CREATE INDEX mv_t_full_idx ON mv_t (x, id, a, b);  -- covering index
```

```
Index Only Scan using mv_t_full_idx on mv_t  (cost=0.42..33.75 rows=990 width=12)
  Index Cond: (x = 10)
```

Answer (score 3):

Since PostgreSQL has BitmapOr, i think you have only to create two indexes of `a` and `b`. Also you can create an index of `id` if necessary.

```
testdb=# CREATE TABLE t (id int, a int, b int);
CREATE TABLE
testdb=# CREATE INDEX t_a_idx ON t (a);
CREATE INDEX
testdb=# CREATE INDEX t_b_idx ON t (b);
CREATE INDEX
testdb=# CREATE INDEX t_id_idx ON t (id);
CREATE INDEX
testdb=# INSERT INTO t SELECT generate_series(0,1000000), 700*random(), 700*random();
INSERT 0 1000001
testdb=# ANALYZE t;
ANALYZE
```

In addition, I create two other indexes:

```
testdb=# CREATE INDEX t_ia_idx ON t (id, a);
CREATE INDEX
testdb=# CREATE INDEX t_ib_idx ON t (id, b);
CREATE INDEX
testdb=# ANALYZE t;
ANALYZE
```

The result of `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` is shown below:

```
testdb=# EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT id,a,b FROM t WHERE a = 10 OR b = 10 order by id;
                                                            QUERY PLAN                                                             
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Sort  (cost=5117.32..5124.33 rows=2803 width=12) (actual time=5.785..5.958 rows=2864 loops=1)
   Sort Key: id
   Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 231kB
   ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on t  (cost=41.26..4956.81 rows=2803 width=12) (actual time=1.430..4.430 rows=2864 loops=1)
         Recheck Cond: ((a = 10) OR (b = 10))
         Heap Blocks: exact=2206
         ->  BitmapOr  (cost=41.26..41.26 rows=2805 width=0) (actual time=1.155..1.155 rows=0 loops=1)
               ->  Bitmap Index Scan on t_a_idx  (cost=0.00..19.94 rows=1406 width=0) (actual time=0.918..0.918 rows=1464 loops=1)
                     Index Cond: (a = 10)
               ->  Bitmap Index Scan on t_b_idx  (cost=0.00..19.92 rows=1399 width=0) (actual time=0.236..0.236 rows=1404 loops=1)
                     Index Cond: (b = 10)
 Planning time: 0.268 ms
 Execution time: 6.137 ms
(13 rows)
```

Comment: So the `t_ia_idx` and `t_ib_idx` indexes not really useful here, right?

Comment: According to my investigation, t_ia_idx and t_ib_idx are not needed. These were prepared for comparison.