# Optimize query to not read all rows in table

Tags: mysql, optimization, query, slow-log

I have this in my slow query log.

## Slow Query Log

```
# Time: 2020-03-09T08:42:46.946084Z
# User@Host: admin_admin[admin_admin] @ localhost [127.0.0.1]  Id:    16
# Query_time: 0.001558  Lock_time: 0.000278 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 255
SET timestamp=1583743366;
select DISTINCT q.id,q.*
            from bot_message_queue q
            left join bot_message_queue_wait w1 on q.botId=w1.botId AND q.chatId=w1.chatId
            left join bot_message_queue_wait w2 on q.botId=w2.botId AND w2.chatId=0
            where
              q.status=0 AND

              (w2.retry_after IS NULL OR w2.retry_after < 1583743366) AND
              (w1.retry_after IS NULL OR w1.retry_after < 1583743366)
            order by q.priority DESC,q.id ASC
            limit 1;
```

## My tables

Following the DDL for the tables involved in the query.

#### bot_message_queue

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `bot_message_queue` (
  `id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `botId` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `chatId` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  `type` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `message` longtext,
  `add_date` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `status` tinyint(2) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT '0=waiting,1=sendig,2=sent,3=error',
  `priority` tinyint(1) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '5' COMMENT '5=normal messages,<5 = bulk messages',
  `delay_after` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '1000',
  `send_date` int(10) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL,
  `identifier` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `botId` (`botId`,`status`),
  KEY `chatId` (`chatId`,`status`),
  KEY `botId_2` (`botId`,`chatId`,`status`,`priority`,`identifier`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
COMMIT;
```

#### bot_message_queue_wait

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `bot_message_queue_wait` (
  `botId` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `chatId` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  `retry_after` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`botId`,`chatId`),
  KEY `retry_after` (`retry_after`),
  KEY `botId` (`botId`,`chatId`,`retry_after`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

--
-- Constraints for dumped tables
--

--
-- Constraints for table `bot_message_queue_wait`
--
ALTER TABLE `bot_message_queue_wait`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `message_queue_wait_botId` FOREIGN KEY (`botId`) REFERENCES `bot` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
COMMIT;
```

## Question

It's not slow, but it is reading the whole table on every request.

What indexes should I change/add to fix this?

## UPDATE

Explain result without distinct

[image: query explain result]

## UPDATE 2

This is a very heavy read/write/update table, its the single most used table in my entire database, usually it has just less than 1000 rows but it could go up to 10000+ when someone is sending bulk messages ...
I clean up processed rows every hour to keep it small ...

Comment: Which version of MySQL is this?

Comment: could you please remove distinct and add output of explain command?

Comment: [Similar](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/110636/)

Comment: you are doing a select distinct * on a table so why would it not read the entire table?

Comment: @mustaccio this case is more complex because query contains conditions on joined table

Comment: @Nikita added the screenshot of the result

Comment: how many rows do your table contain?

Comment: @Nikita updated the question

Comment: according to output of explain the server estimated to read only 6 rows from queue table

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
CREATE INDEX ix_bot_message_queue_status ON bot_message_queue (status, priority desc, id, botId, chatId);           
select q.id
from bot_message_queue q
where
              q.status=0 
              AND
              (NOT EXIST (SELECT 1 FROM bot_message_queue_wait w1 WHERE botId=w1.botId AND q.chatId=w1.chatId) 
              OR EXIST (SELECT 1 FROM bot_message_queue_wait w1 WHERE botId=w1.botId AND q.chatId=w1.chatId AND w1.retry_after < 1583743366))
              AND 
              (NOT EXIST (SELECT 1 FROM bot_message_queue_wait w2 WHERE botId=w2.botId AND 0=w2.chatId) 
              OR EXIST (SELECT 1 FROM bot_message_queue_wait w2 WHERE botId=w2.botId AND 0=w2.chatId AND w2.retry_after < 1583743366))

order by q.priority DESC,q.id ASC
limit 1;
```

you may need to use a trick with generated column if your MySQL version doesn't support descending indexes

Answer (score 0):

Since `retry_after` is `NOT NULL`, you do not need to check for `NULL`.  Removing that check will get rid of `OR`, which prevents sargability.

`ORDER BY q.priority DESC, q.id ASC` probably requires a sort, at least because of the two columns going in opposite directions (DESC/ASC).  (With MySQL 8.0 you could have an index that splits like that.)  Would it work just as well to do `q.id DESC`?  Or maybe invert the values of `q.priority` so both can be `ASC`.  Note: you would have to change all the values and the code; simply using an expression (`-q.priority`) would only make things worse.

The `DISTINCT` effective causes another sort -- to dedup.  With the `LIMIT 1`, who cares if there are dups!

Putting the pieces together:

```
select  q.id
    from  bot_message_queue q
    where  q.status=0
      AND  EXISTS (
        SELECT  1
            FROM  bot_message_queue_wait w1
            WHERE  botId=w1.botId
              AND  q.chatId=w1.chatId
              AND  w1.retry_after < 1583743366
                  )
      AND  EXISTS (
        SELECT  1
            FROM  bot_message_queue_wait w2
            WHERE  botId=w2.botId
              AND  0=w2.chatId
              AND  w2.retry_after < 1583743366
                  )
    order by  q.priority DESC, q.id DESC
    limit  1;
```

And have these indexes for `bot_message_queue`, in the order given.  I don't know which one is better:

```
(status, chatId, priority, id)
(status, priority, id, chatId)
```

and get rid of this on `bot_message_queue_wait`; it is redundant with the data plus the clustered PK:

```
KEY `botId` (`botId`,`chatId`,`retry_after`)
```

Because of the `LIMIT`, you should not trust the "Rows" in `EXPLAIN`.  Instead, use the "Handler counts" technique described here:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#handler_counts